# "Chosen girl in a new and strange world" novel

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I remember the cover was green. Most likely published in the late 1990s to early 2000s.  I remember that it was one of those “chosen girl in a new and strange world” books. I remember it being fairly new. I remember the main issue was some evil something or other destroying planets or something. I remember them (3) standing in some space craft thing trying to make an important decision but the girl not knowing what to do (she must be like 14) and looking to the others for advice.

Comment: If it wasn't for the publishing date I would swear this is Terra's World by Mitch Benn, featuring a planet destroyer, female teenage protagonist in a strange world, spaceships and a green cover.  But it was published in July 2014, so obviously not.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126937/unknown-science-fiction-space-book (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 3):

Could it be ["A Wrinkle in Time" by Madeleine L'Engle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time)?

**"I remember the cover was green. Most likely published in the late 1990s to early 2000s."**

Well, it's been re-released a number of times, but this cover was published in 1998.

[image]
"

**I remember that it was one of those “chosen girl in a new and strange world” books.**

The protagonist, 14 year old Meg Murray, and her brother and a friend are taken to a number of strange worlds in search of her father.

**I remember it being fairly new.**

Well, it was a new release...

**"I remember the main issue was some evil something or other destroying planets or something."**

The big-bad in the story is a personification of evil, called "The Black Thing", which envelopes planets.